# Is it possible to display DHT11 on a 4 digit-7-segment with a PIC16f877A?

Tags: pic, temperature, proteus, 7segmentdisplay, code

I'm trying to display the temperature of the DHT11 on a 4-digit-7-segment. I simulated it on Proteus and the result always equal to 0. I wonder if the way I used timer to display the LED affected the process dht11 sending data
[image]
Here is my code:

```
#include <main2.h>

unsigned int8 MaLed[]={0xC0, 0xF9,0xA4,0x80,0x99, 0x92, 0x82, 0xF8,0x80,0x90};


void hienthi(unsigned int8 x);
  unsigned int8 chuc,donvi,QUET;
     unsigned int8 dh_nhiet_do, dh_nhiet_do2, dh_do_am, dh_do_am2;
     
#INT_TIMER1
void NGAT_TIMER1_QUETLED()
{
   
   hienthi(dh_nhiet_do);
   
    CLEAR_INTERRUPT(INT_TIMER1);
    SETUP_TIMER_1(INT_TIMER1|T1_DIV_BY_8);
   SET_TIMER1(65161);
}
void main()
{

SET_TRIS_D(0);
   SET_TRIS_C(0);
//khai bao bien cuc bo o day
setup_timer_1(T1_INTERNAL|T1_DIV_BY_8);
set_timer1(65161);
enable_interrupts(INT_TIMER1);
enable_interrupts(GlOBAL);

   while(TRUE)
   {
//TODO: User Code
     
  
if(DHT_GetTemHumi (dh_nhiet_do, dh_nhiet_do2, dh_do_am, dh_do_am2))
{
dh_nhiet_do=dh_nhiet_do;

}
delay_ms(500);
      }
   

}
void hienthi(unsigned int8 x)
{

   chuc=x/10;
   donvi=x%10;
   
   QUET=0b11111110;
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
   OUTPUT_C(QUET);
   OUTPUT_d(Maled[chuc]);
   Delay_us(200);
   OUTPUT_D(0xFF);
   QUET=(QUET<<1)+1;
   
 
}
}
```

Here is the main2.h:

```
#include <16F877A.h>
#device ADC=16

#FUSES NOWDT                    //No Watch Dog Timer
#FUSES NOBROWNOUT               //No brownout reset
#FUSES NOLVP                    //No low voltage prgming, B3(PIC16) or B5(PIC18) used for I/O
#FUSES HS

#include <dht.h>
#define LE_1   PIN_C0
#define LE_2   PIN_C1
#define LE_3   PIN_C2
#define LE_4   PIN_C3
```

Here is the DHT.h

```
#define _DHT11_H_

#use delay(crystal=4000000)

#BIT  DHT_DATA_OUT =  0x06.0
#BIT  DHT_DATA_IN  =  0x06.0
#BIT  DHT_DDR_DATA =  0x86.0

#define DHT_ER       0
#define DHT_OK       1

#define DDROUT    0
#define DDRIN     1

unsigned int8 DHT_GetTemHumi(unsigned int8 &tem1,&tem2,unsigned int8 &humi1,&humi2);

unsigned int8 DHT_GetTemHumi(unsigned int8 &tem1,&tem2,unsigned int8 &humi1,&humi2)
{
   unsigned int8 buffer[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
   unsigned int8 ii,i,checksum;
   
   DHT_DDR_DATA=DDROUT;   // set la cong ra
   DHT_DATA_OUT=1;
   delay_us(60);
   DHT_DATA_OUT=0;
   delay_ms(25); // it nhat 18ms
   DHT_DATA_OUT=1;    
   DHT_DDR_DATA=DDRIN;//set la cong vao
   delay_us(60);
   if(DHT_DATA_IN)return DHT_ER ;
   else while(!(DHT_DATA_IN));   //Doi DaTa len 1
   delay_us(60);//cho 60us
   if(!DHT_DATA_IN)return DHT_ER;
   else while((DHT_DATA_IN));    //Doi Data ve 0
   //Bat dau doc du lieu
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      for(ii=0;ii<8;ii++)
      {   
         while((!DHT_DATA_IN));//Doi Data len 1
         delay_us(50);
         if(DHT_DATA_IN)
         {
            buffer[i]|=(1<<(7-ii));
            while((DHT_DATA_IN));//Doi Data xuong 0
         }
      }
   }
   checksum=buffer[0]+buffer[1]+buffer[2]+buffer[3];
   if((checksum)!=buffer[4])return DHT_ER;
   tem1  =   buffer[2];//gia tri phan nguyen
   tem2  =   buffer[3];//gia tri phan thap phan
   humi1 =   buffer[0];//gia tri phan nguyen
   humi2 =   buffer[1];//gia tri phan thap phan
   return DHT_OK;
}
```

Comment: Symbol names in Vietnamese will be difficult to debug for users on this site, I think.

Comment: Since you use a simulator, add a logic analyzer/scope to the data line of the DHT11 and check the signal. [Edit] your question and add your findings.